# Correct use of input file in perl?

Tags: perl, input, while-loop

database.Win.txt is a file that contains a multiple of 3 lines. The second of every three lines is a number. The code is supposed to print out the three lines (in a new order) on one line separated by tabs, but only if the second line is 1.

Am I, by this code, actually getting the loop to create an array with three lines of database.Win.txt each time it runs through the loop? That's my goal, but I suspect this isn't what the code does, since I get an error saying that the int() function expects a numeric value, and doesn't find one.

```
while(<database.Win.txt>){
    $new_entry[0] = <database.Win.txt>;
    $new_entry[1] = <database.Win.txt>;
    $new_entry[2] = <database.Win.txt>;
    if(int($new_entry[1]) == 1) {
        chomp($new_entry);
        print "$new_entry[1], \t $new_entry[2], \t $new_entry[0], \n"
    } 
}
```

I am a total beginner with Perl. Please explain as simply as possible!

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got a good start on the solution.  However, your `while` reads one line right before the next three lines are read (if those were `<$file_handles>`).  `int` isn't necessary, but `chomp` is--before you check the value of `$new_entry[1]` else there's still a record separator at the end.

Given this, consider the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @entries;
open my $fh, '<', 'database.Win.txt' or die $!;

while (1) {
    last if eof $fh;
    chomp( $entries[$_] = <$fh> ) for 0 .. 2;

    if ( $entries[1] == 1 ) {
        print +( join "\t", @entries ), "\n";
    }
}

close $fh;
```

Always start with `use strict; use warnings`.  Next, open the file using the [three-argument form](http://modernperlbooks.com/mt/2010/04/three-arg-open-migrating-to-modern-perl.html) of `open`.  A `while (1)` is used here, so three lines at a time can be read within the `while` loop.  Since it's an 'infinite' `while` loop, the `last if eof $fh;` gives a way out, viz., if the next file read produces an end of file, it's the `last`.  Right below that is a `for` loop that effectively does what you did: assign a file line to an array position.  Note that `chomp` is used to remove the record separator during the assignment.  The last part is also similar to yours, as it checks whether the second of the three lines is 1, and then the line is printed if it is.

Hope this helps!